# How can I duplicate a project and change the name properly?

Tags: ios, xcode-organizer

I duplicated an project to make a similar app. I am trying to submit both to the app store. However, the duplicated app has a slight naming issue(in organizer):

[image: issue]

My intended name is underlined in red, while the blue is the project name of my previous app. What are the differences between these two separate names?

edit: for those who can't read Chinese or can't tell, the two names are different.

Answer (score 2):

The one underlined in red is App Display Name which may be in localized.strings as set in the info.plist.
The blue underlined name is the product name, as set in the build settings.

Comment: I cannot find  App location Display name in info.plist. I have changed executable file. I am using Xcode 6